# onShowFileChooser() só funciona uma vez

Tags: android, webview

Eu tenho uma aplicação Android consumindo uma pagina WEB e implementando algumas funcionalidades para o usuário. O problema aparece quando eu tento anexar arquivos de mídia do aparelho Android para enviar ao servidor mais de uma vez; ele deixa de funcionar. O método onShowFileChooser() só é chamado apenas uma vez e depois para de funcionar, eu encontrei o mesmo problema [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666844/onshowfilechooser-from-android-webview-works-only-once) e tentei implementar todas as soluções propostas mas não consegui resolver, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Método *onShowFileChooser*:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    if(mFilePathCallback != null)
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
    mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

    Log.d("DEBUG", "onShowFileChooser() ACIONADO!");

    Intent intent = null;
    if (fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()[0].contains(IMAGE_TYPE) &&
            fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()[0].contains(VIDEO_TYPE))
        intent = createFileSelectIntent();
    else if (fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()[0].contains(IMAGE_TYPE))
        intent = createPictureIntent();
    else if(fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()[0].contains(VIDEO_TYPE))
        intent = createVideoIntent();

    if (intent!=null)
        startActivityForResult(intent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    return true;
}
```

Método *onActivityResult*:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            Uri[] results = new Uri[]{};

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                FileBean fileBean = null;
                if (data != null && data.getDataString()!=null) {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Utils.getRealPath(this, dataString));
                    fileBean = new FileBean(uri, Utils.getFileType(uri.getPath()));
                }
                else if (filePath != null)
                    fileBean = new FileBean(Uri.parse(filePath), Utils.getFileType(filePath));

                if (fileBean != null) {
                    ApplicationStateSingleton.getInstance().getFileBeanList().add(fileBean);
                    results = new Uri[]{fileBean.getUri()};
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
            return;
        }

        if (mFilePathCallbackKitKat != null) {
            Uri result = null;

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                FileBean fileBean = null;
                if (data != null && data.getDataString()!=null) {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Utils.getRealPath(this, dataString));
                    fileBean = new FileBean(uri, Utils.getFileType(uri.getPath()));
                }
                else if (filePath != null)
                        fileBean = new FileBean(Uri.parse(filePath), Utils.getFileType(filePath));

                if (fileBean != null) {
                    ApplicationStateSingleton.getInstance().getFileBeanList().add(fileBean);
                    result = fileBean.getUri();
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallbackKitKat.onReceiveValue(result);
            mFilePathCallbackKitKat = null;
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Essas são as classes que eu jugo serem pertinentes para a resolução do problema, no entanto, se precisarem de mais fragmentos de código avisem.